# Accessing Google Cloud Datastore locally from ASP.NET throws Grpc.Core.RpcException: "Missing or insufficient permissions."

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm following the [Using Cloud Datastore with .NET](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) tutorial. At some point it says that you can run the provided project locally by just pressing F5. When I do that I get the following exception

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=PermissionDenied, Detail="Missing or insufficient permissions.")'

This exception is thrown exactly at the `_db.RunQuery(query)` line.

```
var query = new Query("Book") { Limit = pageSize };
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nextPageToken))
    query.StartCursor = ByteString.FromBase64(nextPageToken);
var results = _db.RunQuery(query);`
```

If I deploy the application to cloud it works as expected, no error. I've given datastore owner permissions to all accounts in Cloud IAM (Identity and Access Management) but it still doesn't work. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like the credentials you're using locally aren't appropriate - what credentials *are* you using? If you download the service account JSON and set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to point to that file, it should be absolutely fine. (I do this all the time.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't quite understand that there were multiple service accounts. For the [.NET Bookshelf app tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/tutorial-app) I created a new compute engine that apparently has a new service account, and that one had no keys created. After I downloaded the json key it works as expected.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "a new compute engine" - but each Google Cloud Platform project has its own set of service accounts, yes. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that each project has multiple service accounts. 


About  the Compute Engine, if you look into the Bookshelf tutorial linked above there's the 'Creating a Compute Engine instance' step in which you need to setup a new Compute Engine instance. This has a separate service account that I needed to use in order to have read permissions to the cloud datastore.

Comment: Hmm... you shouldn't a separate service account for each Compute Engine instance. The service account is associated with the project, not the instance. It sounds like you may have two projects - one that you enabled Datastore with, and one that you downloaded the service account for before.

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Skeet pointed out, I was using the wrong json key locally. Previously I created a compute engine that has a separate service account. After I downloaded a new json key from *Console -> IAM & Admin -> Service Accounts* it worked locally as well.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  I chose the roles too narrowly at first.  So I just created a new service account and gave it owner access for now.  I can dial the access back later.