# Firestore C#: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently exploring Firebase's Cloud Firestore in C# and has encountered with the error which I could not resolve after searching SO. It seems that the resources for Firestore in C# is quite limited:

```
"Status(StatusCode=PermissionDenied, Detail=\"Missing or insufficient permissions.\")"
```

My code so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "FirebaseCsharpTest.json");

        string project = "MyProjectId";

        FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(project);
        Console.WriteLine("Created Cloud Firestore client with project ID: {0}", project);

        AddPerson(db).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }

    public static async Task AddPerson(FirestoreDb db)
    {
        CollectionReference collection = db.Collection("users");
        DocumentReference document = await collection.AddAsync(new
        {
            Name = new
            { First = "Ada", Last = "Lovelace" },
            Born = 1815
        });
    }
}
```

I have checked on my Firebase console that the Firestore security rules are set to public (as of now, for testing sake). I have also ensured that the authentication `json` file is the right file generated from Google Developer Console as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719868/accessing-google-cloud-datastore-locally-from-asp-net-throws-grpc-core-rpcexcept).

Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT:
My permissions on google cloud console:
[image]

Comment: Im having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Do check the projectID that you have been adding.
ProjectID is supposed to be the one that is specified in your json file.

Comment: Thanks. I was passing the project name instead.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add the `Firebase Viewer` role to the service account that was trying to use firestore. In my case this was cloud run.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Cloud IAM issue and not a security rule issues. [The C# server client library creates a privileged server environment that doesn't take into account Cloud Firestore security rules.](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/libraries#server_client_libraries). It seems that either your key file's service account doesn't have the correct IAM role or your code is not finding your keyfile.

Try using the full path to your keyfile instead of the relative path.

You can also try setting up a new service account and key file as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers#set_up_authentication).

Also, make sure you are changing the `project` variable:

```
string project = "NewFirebaseCsharpTest";

FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(project);
```

Comment: What should i be looking out for on the console? I followed the instruction to set up new service account key, and have also tried full path of keyfile, but still throw the same error. In the IAM, I can only see my email and my role as owner. What am I missing?

Comment: I have also added an image on what i see on the google cloud console. Pls advice what am I missing. Thanks

Comment: IAM permission looks fine. Make sure to update the `project` variable with your project ID. Updated my answer.

Comment: I can't use that id as its not available on Firestore. I have used the projectId on Firestore instead, but still unable to get any further.

Answer (score 0):

**Change the string `project` to the Id of the project and not the name of the project. The Id will probably start with the name and have a numeric suffix.**

If that fails, go to the Log Explorer and query the logs. You will see an error that explains why your permission was denied.

You're never going to get enough information from the client-side for security reasons. Google isn't going to tell someone trying to gain access to something they shouldn't have access to what is going wrong. But, an admin can view the logs on the other side which will log all the information.